# How to check bottomsheet is opened or closed

Tags: react-native

Here is my code:

```
if(refRBSheet.current?.open()){
              refRBSheet.current.close();
            }
```

In my React Native application I am implementing 'react-native-raw-bottom-sheet'. I want to check if the RBSheet is open, and if it is then I want to close it. The above code open's the RBSheet instead of closing.

Comment: You can do so through state management or event listeners. Set a state when you open the sheet and listen to the state change in "useEffect" method. The same effect can be handled with the custom events too.

Comment: can you post any code samples

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the library [documentation](https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet#props), it supports `onOpen` and `onClose` event functions. Use them to save the open/closed state of the bottom sheet.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import RBSheet from 'react-native-raw-bottom-sheet';

const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const refRBSheet = useRef();

  const onPress = () => {
    if (!open) {
      refRBSheet.current.open();
    } else {
      refRBSheet.current.close();
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Button title="Open" onPress={onPress} />
      </View>
      <RBSheet
        ref={refRBSheet}
        onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        // .....
      >
        <Button title="Close" onPress={onPress} />
      </RBSheet>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```